# Python:How to insert array of data into mongodb using pymongo from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo

Have a dataframe with values

df

```
name     rank  subject  marks  age  
tom      123    math     25     10
mark     124    math     50     10
```

How to insert the dataframe data into mongodb using pymongo like first two columns as a regular insert and another 3 as array

```
{
    "_id":  "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
    "name":"tom",
    "rank":"123"
    "scores": [{
        "subject": "math",
        "marks": 25,
        "age": 10
    }]
}

{
    "_id":  "507f1f77bcf86cd799439012",
    "name":"mark",
    "rank":"124"
    "scores": [{
        "subject": "math",
        "marks": 50,
        "age": 10
    }]
}
```

tried this :

```
convert_dict = df.to_dict("records")

mydb.school_data.insert_many(convert_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution

```
convert_dict = df.to_dict(orient="records")

mydb.school_data.insert_many(convert_dict)
```